# Showing non Objective-C variables in debug watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to watch a char* in XCode, but when I type **po sql** or **po *sql** in output, I get nothing, but just **no Objective-C description available** in output.

```
char sql[255];
sprintf(sql,"blah blah blah",blah,blah,blah);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `p`, instead of `po`.

`po` is for objects, `p` is for plain C variables.

If it complains about not knowing the type, just explicitly cast it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `printf`

```
printf "%s", sql
```

or

```
p (char)sql
```

Comment: You can also use `NSLog(@"%s", sql);`